# Adding Commas to Animated Number Counter

Tags: javascript, animation, numbers, counter

I have been experimenting with different combinations of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript that would give me an animated number counter on scroll with a symbol next to each number (+, %, etc.). I finally found the right combination; however, it is not perfect yet. I would like to add a comma to numbers 1,000 and above, but when I add commas in the HTML, it produces a NaN output. I am very new to JavaScript and I have no clue what to add or fix in my current code to show commas.

Would someone be able to rewrite my current code to show commas or guide me in how to do this? I would greatly appreciate any assistance!

```
<script>
function inVisible(element) {
  //Checking if the element is
  //visible in the viewport
  var WindowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var WindowBottom = WindowTop + $(window).height();
  var ElementTop = element.offset().top;
  var ElementBottom = ElementTop + element.height();
  //animating the element if it is
  //visible in the viewport
  if ((ElementBottom <= WindowBottom) && ElementTop >= WindowTop)
    animate(element);
}

function animate(element) {
  //Animating the element if not animated before
  if (!element.hasClass('ms-animated')) {
    var maxval = element.data('max');
    var html = element.html();
    element.addClass("ms-animated");
    $({
      countNum: element.html()
    }).animate({
      countNum: maxval
    }, {
      //duration 2 seconds
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        element.html(Math.floor(this.countNum) + html);
      },
      complete: function() {
        element.html(this.countNum + html);
      }
    });
  }
}
//When the document is ready
$(function() {
  //This is triggered when the
  //user scrolls the page
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    //Checking if each items to animate are
    //visible in the viewport
    $("h2[data-max]").each(function() {
      inVisible($(this));
    });
  })
});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to remove the comma before doing calculations with the number.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I no longer have commas in the HTML, but the numbers are still showing as 1000 instead of 1,000. Is there any way to fix this in the code above?

Comment: Sorry, where exactly in the code are you trying to insert the comma?

Comment: Oh my goodness - this worked! You are a life saver! Thank you so much, Barmar! :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas when reading the HTML, add them back when displaying.

```
function animate(element) {
  //Animating the element if not animated before
  if (!element.hasClass('ms-animated')) {
    var maxval = element.data('max');
    var html = element.html();
    element.addClass("ms-animated");
    $({
      countNum: parseInt(element.html().replace(/,/g, '')) // remove commas
    }).animate({
      countNum: maxval
    }, {
      //duration 2 seconds
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        element.html((Math.floor(this.countNum) + html).toLocaleString());
      },
      complete: function() {
        element.html((Math.floor(this.countNum) + html).toLocaleString());
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format a locale-aware number via `toLocaleString`:

```js
function formatHeading(headingText, duration) {
  return `${Math.floor(duration).toLocaleString('en-US')} ${headingText}`;
};
```

### Full example

```js
// When the document is ready
$(function() {
  // This is triggered when the user scrolls the page
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Checking if each items to animate are visible in the viewport
    $("h2[data-max]").each(function() {
      animateIfVisible($(this));
    });
  })
});

function animateIfVisible($element) {
  // Checking if the element is visible in the viewport
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();
  var elementTop = $element.offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $element.height();
  // Animating the element if it is visible in the viewport
  if ((elementBottom <= windowBottom) && elementTop >= windowTop) {
    animate($element);
  }
}

function formatHeading(headingText, duration) {
  return `${Math.floor(duration).toLocaleString('en-US')} ${headingText}`;
};

function animate($element) {
  // Animating the element if not animated before
  if (!$element.hasClass('ms-animated')) {
    var maxValue = $element.data('max');
    var headingText = $element.text();
    $element.addClass("ms-animated");
    $({
      elapsedTime: 0
    }).animate({
      elapsedTime: maxValue
    }, {
      // Duration 2 seconds
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $element.text(formatHeading(headingText, this.elapsedTime));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $element.text(formatHeading(headingText, this.elapsedTime));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="2000">Foo</h2>
<h2 data-max="1000">Foo</h2>
```